# Could not find method butonCap(View) in a parent or ancestor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been searching the error for about 2 hours on google , i can't figure out what it's wrong . It just force closes when I tap the button "butonCap", I didn't work with fragments until now

ERROR:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method butonCap(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'cap'
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Butoane.java  - i just made another java file because i can't write any code in the fragment java file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_fata);

     final Button butonCap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cap);
    butonCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent butonCap = new Intent(Butoanele.this, capul.class);
            Butoanele.this.startActivity(butonCap);
        }
    });
}
}
```

fragment_fata.xml   - this is just one of the 2 fragments from navigation view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentFata"
android:background="@drawable/fata">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_outline"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:onClick="butonCap"
        android:text="Cap"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class should extends Fragment and inflate layout in onCreateView() callback. 
Call getActivity().findViewById in onViewCreated() callback.

[watch this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Answer (score 0):

In fragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            //Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fata, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (getView() == null) {
                    return;
            }

            final Button butonCap = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.cap);
            butonCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getView().getContext(), capul.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });
    }
```